# How do I get "historical" impulse responses from SVAR results in R?

Tags: r, variables

My current analysis involves using a 7-variable SVAR model based on U.S. data from 1992 to 2022. Now I am trying to visualise impulse reponses of one variable to another shock on the same time range (i.e. 92-22).

However, the function `irf()` from the package `vars` seems to return only "forecasts" rather than historical trends and therefore doesn't align with what I need.

Is there any other function I should try to make my analysis possible, or my understanding of IRF has gone wrong (that I should only set up initial values and see what happens)?

```r
VARselect(y = dt[, c("CP","PL","FP","IX","GDP","MP","MD")], 
          lag.max = 10, type = c("none"))

# SVAR restrictions
amat <- diag(7)
amat[2, 1] <- NA

amat[3, 1] <- NA
amat[3, 2] <- NA

amat[4, 1] <- NA
amat[4, 2] <- NA
amat[4, 3] <- NA

amat[5, 1] <- NA
amat[5, 2] <- NA
amat[5, 3] <- NA
amat[5, 4] <- NA

amat[6, 1] <- NA
amat[6, 2] <- NA
amat[6, 5] <- NA

amat[7, 2] <- NA
amat[7, 5] <- NA
amat[7, 6] <- NA

sv <- cbind(dt$CP, dt$PL, dt$FP, dt$IX/100, dt$GDP, dt$MP,dt$MD)
colnames(sv) <- cbind("CP", "PL", "FP", "IX", "GDP", "MP", "MD")

var1 <- VAR(sv, p = 1, season = NULL, exog = NULL, type = "none")
svar1 <- SVAR(var1, Amat = amat, Bmat = NULL, hessian = TRUE,
              estmethod = c("scoring", "direct"))

oir <- irf(svar1, n.ahead = 10)

plot(oir)
```

This is a sample of the data (original data [here on google docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bvyudotf5o6XcPrwwoa86tRe1bGPZMN6/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114979342361963585841&rtpof=true&sd=true)):

```r
dt <- structure(list(Date = c("1/03/1992", "1/06/1992", "1/09/1992", 
"1/12/1992", "1/03/1993", "1/06/1993", "1/09/1993", "1/12/1993", 
"1/03/1994", "1/06/1994", "1/09/1994", "1/12/1994", "1/03/1995", 
"1/06/1995", "1/09/1995", "1/12/1995"), CP = c(0.0852348, 0.0963323, 
0.0386897, -0.0239949, -0.0462276, 0.0090411, -0.0671644, -0.0610149, 
-0.0404173, 0.0758628, 0.0263797, -0.0116829, 0.0357452, 0.050837, 
-0.0680809, 0.0546443), PL = c(0.337379872734604, 0.214951333434265, 
0.260855606869013, 0.141492743366049, 0.39778076343206, 0.185378892041148, 
0.161396876897097, 0.160714035130045, 0.319059105231211, 0.18089840707363, 
0.314346438190937, 0.066904556165947, 0.377116153925184, 0.241619470650149, 
0.152833917664674, 0.0654015939317388), FP = c(0.0248441, 0.013828, 
0.0125275, 0.0102347, 0.0017216, 0.0059541, 0.0105912, 0.0090526, 
-0.0063763, 0.0125353, 0.0194767, 0.0145381, 0.0148225, 0.0108805, 
-0.0044964, 0.0063926), IX = c(100, 100.4359086, 101.0451944, 
101.1506369, 91.22192999, 100.7711784, 100.736254, 100.6682777, 
104.3650311, 101.269644, 101.6012428, 101.0208064, 100.4775907, 
100.6242852, 100.6363857, 100.7702137), GDP = c(0.0119716, 0.0108432, 
0.0098811, 0.0104288, 0.0016698, 0.0058211, 0.0047716, 0.0136008, 
0.0097031, 0.013551, 0.0058454, 0.0114552, 0.003547, 0.0029831, 
0.0085066, 0.0067904), MP = c(0.03529292, 0.034197986, 0.028495008, 
0.027575771, 0.029254778, 0.031366293, 0.030376446, 0.031274461, 
0.036875159, 0.046837812, 0.050768406, 0.071169659, 0.059993919, 
0.05677472, 0.055419045, 0.053324613), MD = c(0.01771322540377, 
0.00756659376399, 0.01182431240935, 0.01345257180299, 0.00231531162295, 
0.0142624696554, 0.01182414310964, 0.01212252869281, 0.00596743249214, 
0.00424165799069, 0.00313993553234, 0.00097371489691, 0.00040831636274, 
0.00535168228122, 0.01403930673755, 0.00829166033065)), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share some code you tried and data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: Hi @Quinten, I have updated the description and you can find the code and data. Thank you!